# Using single for updating different fields

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table named '`tblProperties`' in SQL server which has the fields as

```
productid
length
weight
height
depth
```

i will update `length,weight,height` at different intervals. 
Now I am writing a separate update stored procedure for each property update.

how can we write single update query/SP for all so that i can pass '`productid`' and the update field like `weight` or `height` etc..

Comment: I seriously wonder why you would bother writing a stored procedure when plain SQL will do fine

Comment: @Bohemian: To only GRANT EXECUTE rights rather than SELECT, UPDATE, INSERT, DELETE, possibly?

Comment: @AndriyM Yeah, but talk about obfuscating permissions. Surely it's easier and more straightforward to grant update etc to users. Unless you need to grant on specific columns I suppose. Basically, I'm anti-stored procs.

Comment: @Bohemian: Specific columns and/or specific rows. You can use a user ID parameter in your SP to check if they are allowed to retrieve/modify a specific subset of the table(s). Anyway, I can see how SP-less environment can be clearer to those used to it than the one where SPs are heavily employed. So, I guess, to each his own.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
declare @length INT, @weight INT, @height INT, @depth INT
set @length = 7878
SET @weight = NULL
SET @height = NULL
SET @depth = NULL


update tblProperties
SET length= (CASE WHEN @length IS NULL THEN length ELSE @length END),
    weight = (CASE WHEN @weight IS NULL THEN weight ELSE @weight END),
    height = (CASE WHEN @height IS NULL THEN height ELSE @height END),
    depth = (CASE WHEN @depth IS NULL THEN depth ELSE @depth END),
WHERE productid = xxxxxxx
```

Comment: +1. You can also use `SET item = ISNULL(@item, item)` or `SET item = COALESCE(@item, item)`.

Comment: Thanks @simon .. that is working fine..
one more thing i need to clarify.. Is there any performance issue by using this instead of separate queries??

Comment: Talking about performance, I think Andriy idea is better, which is using the COALESCE keyword